# How to inject tailwind css into an iframe without using play cdn of tailwind

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, iframe, tailwind-css

I'm working with svelte and made a chat widget, for styling I used tailwindcss.
the main problem with the chat widgets are you have to render them in an iframe so that it doesn't disturb the css of its remote site. so I achieved loading it inside iframe but it rendered without tailwind styles.

`// main.ts is my file where I declared the iframe`

```
import './app.css';
import App from './App.svelte';


// you can ignore this interface if you find it confusing

interface IWidget {
    iframeContainer: HTMLElement | null;
    init: (props: any) => void;
    createContainer: () => void;
    handleMessage: (event: MessageEvent) => void;
    setupListeners: () => void;
    
}



const app = (() => {
    // new App({
    //  target: document.getElementById('app'),
    // });
    const iframeContainer = document.createElement('div');
    iframeContainer.id = 'my-chat-widget';
    document.body.appendChild(iframeContainer);

    // create iframe
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.id = 'my-chat-iframe';
    iframe.srcdoc = `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>My Support</title>
                <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
                <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
                <link
                    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700&display=swap"
                    rel="stylesheet"
                />
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="my-widget"></div>
            </body>
        </html>`;
    document.getElementById('my-chat-widget').appendChild(iframe);
    const iframeWindow: HTMLIFrameElement =
        document.getElementById('my-chat-iframe');

    document.getElementById('my-chat-iframe').onload = () => {
        new App({
            target: iframeWindow.contentWindow.document.getElementById('my-widget'),
        });
    };
})();

export default app;
```

the file above is similar to `index.tsx` in react

Basically I'm directly targeting my svelte app into the iframe, only the problem I'am facing is the tailwind css is not loading.

methods I tried

- adding Play CDN link from tailwind into `head` of above file.
  (this worked but not feasible as production build)
- directly linking the `app.css` into `head` of above file.
  (this also worked but only in dev mode because the bundler adds its content hash, I want it to be production ready)